# On child hover change the css of Parent

Tags: html, css

I want to change the css of parent on hover of Child element.

```
<ul id="main-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Private Limited
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#0">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Industry</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li></ ul>
```

What i want is if i hover on li of **submenu**, li of **main-menu** get highlighted.

Comment: not possible with css

Comment: Implement jQuery. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic : i want to try it with css only

Comment: @Mr_Green : Can you suggest something.

Comment: You can do it with CSS. I have before. But I can tell you right now it will make it so much easier on you if you implement JavaScript.

Comment: I suggested that it is not possible with css. go with JavaScript.

Comment: @Mr_Green it is, you just have to use a class selector :-) It just won't work EXACTLY the way you want it to...

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic I don't know how you will do that. I highly doubt we can cover all cases using just css though. Anyway, happy to learn if you know that. please share.

Comment: @Mr_Green yeah nah, there are a lot of restrictions from using just CSS. But it is possible to get some sort of an effect with just CSS.

Comment: @WebStarter explain what exactly you want. there might be workaround.

Comment: @Mr_Green : I m using this for navigation menu, where i have to highlight main menu on hover of child submenu.

Comment: There is no parent selector, but you are already hovering over the parent element while hovering over the child. Use that fact to achive what you want

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As already mentioned there is no parent selector but if you recognise that you are already hovering over the parent you can achieve what you want.

A rough example:

```css
#main-menu > li:hover > a
{
  background-color: #F00;
}

#main-menu >  li > .submenu > li:hover
{
  background-color:#00F;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Private Limited
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#0">Company</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#0">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#0">Industry</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the real deal! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As other posts say there is no parent selector.

This is how it should work:

```
li:has(> i:hover) { /* styles to apply to the li tag */ }
```

What this does is check if `li` has a `i` with `:hover` state in it. If that's the case it applies the css. Unfortunately this is not supported yet..

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you want trigger a child element with a child element use this.

```css
.triggerDiv{
  display:none;
}
.child:hover ~.triggerDiv {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="triggerDiv">
      <p>I'm Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can go..

```
For Apply CSS..

$("#main-menu li").mouseover(function()
{ 
      $("#main-menu a:eq(0)").css({'color':'blue','font-weight':'bold'});
});

For Remove CSS..

$("#main-menu li").mouseout(function()
{ 
     $("#main-menu a:eq(0)").removeAttr("style");
});
```

[link]
(https://jsfiddle.net/aj23whnb/)

Comment: I think u didn't got my question, my question is i have to highlight parent menu on hover of child menu

Comment: I understood your question. the code I put here is doing exactly what you want. Please try it

Comment: i want it using CSS only

Comment: @shivani If he wanted to do it with JQuery  he will add the JQuery tag moreover you can still answer partially suggesting how to do it with JQuery

Comment: Of course you can use JS. Maybe the OP had to be more explicit by saying "CSS-only", but it is pretty obvious to most.